# Replace query string returns only first array value using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

My url is having a parameter value as follows below:

```
Nr=AND(OR(abc:def),OR(ghi:jkl),OR(mno:pqr)...)
```

Used the below regex expression to extract the above query string successfully but it returns only the first array value For Ex. getting only abc and def value in the array.

```
OR\(([^:]*):([^)]*)\)
```

I wanted to extract all the values as two separate array values as abc,ghi,mno and def,jkl,pqr...

Plz find my code below:

```
var getNrValue = 'AND(OR(Analyzed:abc),OR(Compounds:def),OR(Chemical:mno))';
var regex = /OR\(([^:]*):([^)]*)\)/gm;
var s = regex.exec(getNrValue);
console.log(s);
```

any help on this?

Comment: Show us the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([^():]+):([^():]+)
```

In the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF0jO5), the right pane shows the capture groups. There is also a [live JS demo](http://js.do/code/39949).

Use this code to create the arrays (see the output of the [live JS demo](http://js.do/code/39949)):

```
var array1 = []; 
var array2 = []; 
var string = 'Nr=AND(OR(abc:def),OR(ghi:jkl),OR(mno:pqr)...)'
    var string = 'Nr=AND(OR(abc:def),OR(ghi:jkl),OR(mno:pqr)...)'
    var myregex = /([^():]+):([^():]+)/g;
    var thematch = myregex.exec(string);
    while (thematch != null) {
        // add it to array of captures
        array1.push(thematch[1]);
        array2.push(thematch[2]);
        document.write("left side: ",thematch[1],"<br />"); 
        document.write("right side: ",thematch[2],"<br />"); 
        // match the next one
        thematch = myregex.exec(string);
    }
```

**Explanation:**

- `([^():]+)` captures to Group 1 any characters that are not parentheses `()`or colons `:`
- `:`
- `([^():]+)` captures to Group 2 any characters that are not parentheses `()`or colons `:`
- the code retrieves Group 1 and Group 2 matches and pushes them onto the two arrays

Let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: just let me know if my query parameter has the below changes like Nr=AND(OR(abc:def,abc:aaa,abc:ddd),OR(ghi:jkl,ghi:ggg,ghi:ghg),OR(mno:pqr,mno:ppp,mno:qqq)...). Additional values are getting added here..